# Javascript: Functions get called on page load instead of onclick/onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, alert

I'm relatively new to JS, but I have programmed in C before, and I'm trying to get my head around the whole event driven nature of it. I'm trying to create a script that will validate form input, however all of my code is being run - everything inside if/else, loops, what have you - regardless of the event happening or not. To test, and to make it easier to post here, I've written a simple program that has this problem too.

HTML:

```
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = alert("hello");
}

window.onload = init;
```

From what I understand, the init function should be called when the page loads (window.onload), and the alert should pop up when the button with the ID "test" is clicked (onclick). What is actually happening is that the alert is popping up as soon as the page loads, and will pop up again if I hit the button.

My thinking is that I've made some incorrect assumptions about the order in which JS is executed, but I cant think of what that is. Is anyone able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not right, it should be:

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = function () { alert("hello"); };
}
```

This is because you need in JavaScript you need to assign the function itself to the `click` event (alert is a function).

Take this for example:

```
function hello() {
    alert("hello");
}

document.getElementById("test").onclick = hello;
```

Note that I didn't put the brackets `()` after `hello` function? That's because I'm using a reference to the function itself. If I put the brackets, I'm actually **evaluating** that function at the point in time of the click assignment happening.

So doing:

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = hello();
```

Will show the alert will show the `alert` **immediately** after this line has been executed.

Comment: In other words: `x = alert()` means: `x` is the returned value of the `alert()` statment. And what is the returned value? Let’s execute it to find out — and that’s where the execution happens!

Comment: Thanks for replying! That makes sense, actually. But how would I pass a variable to be used by the function triggered that I also want to use in the parent function? Or would I simply use a global variable?

Comment: You'd have to wrap the function call itself into a function, something like: `onclick = function () { myFunction(myVariable); };` that will have the same scope

Answer (score 2):

yes your javascript function will call only when page will load .If you also want to call that init() function on click Test button so please try like this :

JavaScript:

```js
function init(){ alert("hello"); }

window.onload = init;
```

```html
HTML: 
<button id="test" onClick='init()'>Test</button>
```